# Selling a book based on CC BY-SA

Tags: commercial, cc-by-sa

My company would like to make a book mostly adapted from CC-BY-SA licenced text. I understand this is legal if we distribute the adapted text under the same licence. But what if we add to the book our own copyrighted images? Can you licence the text under CC-BY-SA and keep our copyright on the images?

How would the situation change in the case of CC-BY licenced text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Distributing images alongside text creates a combined work, but not a derivative work, and your images are not bound by the CC BY-SA requirements.

Allowing the distributing of books of CC BY-SA licensed text is very much the intention of the license, and expressly legal. You are correct that the license mandates your text is available under CC BY-SA as well.

If the original text were under CC BY (not SA) there would be no requirement that your adapted text was available under the same license.

Comment: … only that you properly attribute the original work.

Comment: Yes, all conditions of the license, including attribution, need to be met.